# Angular Custom Google Search Bar only working on reload

Tags: html, angular, typescript, google-search

I am trying to integrate a Google custom search / programmable search bar into my angular application. It only works if I reload the website.

On first site visit:

[image: Website without loaded search]

As soon as I refresh/ reload the Website (pressing: F5) the results are loaded:

[image: Loaded Search Results]

I have pasted the code that is generated by google inside the component:

```
<div class="gcse-searchresults-only"></div>
```

The necessary Javascript from Google is added to the index.html of the module:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Try Google Search</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=e8453de87d4ac0ce5"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is pretty old - but I searched high and low for a solution to exactly this issue. I created a site using Angular and my GCSE search tool would *only* show up after F5'ing the page.

I finally found this and it solved my problems:

In my `searchpage.component.html`:

```
<div id="searchbox"></div>
```

And in my `searchpage.component.ts` (under ngOnInit):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadScriptsSearchBox();
};

loadScriptsSearchBox(): any {


    var gcseDiv = document.getElementById('searchbox');
    gcseDiv.innerHTML = '<gcse:search></gcse:search>'

    var cx = '###uniqueid###';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);


}
```